# Proving a numerical inequality without using a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove $2^{28}>5^{11}$. It reduces to proving $28 > 11.\log_25$. But how should I verify it theoretically without using a calculator?

I was looking for a general theorem verifying such inequalities but apparently some numerical calculations are unavoidable.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that $2^7>5^3$.

Comment: Alternatively:
$$ 2^{28} = 2^{10(2.8)} > 10^{3(2.8)} = 10^{8.4} $$
and
$$ 5^{11} = \frac{10^{11}}{2^{11}} < \frac{10^{11}}{10^{3(1.1)}} = 10^{7.7} $$

Answer (score 4):

Since $\;2^7=128>125=5^3\;,\;$ it follows that

$\left(2^7\right)^4>\left(5^3\right)^4\;,$

$2^{28}>5^{12}>5^{11}\;,$

hence ,

$2^{28}>5^{11}\;.$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, similarly to the hint given by Gregory in the comments, we have

$$2^{28}>5^{11} \iff 2^{28}2^{11}>5^{11}2^{11}\iff 2^{39}>10^{11}$$

and

$$2^{39}=\left(2^{10}\right)^{3.9}>\left(10^{3}\right)^{3.9}=10^{11.7 }>10^{11}$$